# How do add a solid color in footerView in a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, drawerlayout

I want to add a solid color in footerView in this ListFragment.

I have tried to set a backgroundColor on listview.

```
lv = getListView();
lv.setDividerHeight(0);
lv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

Also have tried to add a footerview with LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

```
lv.addFooterView(buildlabel2());
```

And nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: Try to add footer before adapter set

Comment: @MD is right you should add footer view prior setting listview adapter, also check your xml layout containing listview that its height should be `match_parent` like:  `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: take a picture of the solid color and place it as a background of the List. Picture should be as big as the screen (height)

Comment: add a footer before adapter isnt exactly the problem, it add the view but it needs to match the screensize, put a blank image with match_parent doenst work